# what is the logic behind these ladder lines

Tags: plc, ladder

I have a ladder diagram for timing porpose.(keyence KV-24DR)
some instructions are repeated many times but I dont understand what are these for.
can anybody help me?

the confusing thing is that the program increments a number(I think it should be positive) and then compares it with '0' !!!

[image]
2002: Always ON relay

LDA(DM0021): load A from data memory #0021

ADD(#00001): Adds value specified by operand to contents of internal register, and inputs result back to same internal register.

CMP(#00000): Compares content of internal register and value specified by operand.

DW(#00000)(DM#00021): writes #00000 to data memory #000021

[image]
here is keyence programming manual:

https://gofile.io/d/jITBhK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is just clamping each of the variables DM0021, 22 and 23 to the range 0 to 99. If it is inside the limits it leaves it alone.

[image]